# Remainder when product is divided by 11

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Consider a sequence of natural numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ given by:

$a_k=11^{k+2}+12^{2k+1}$

Find the remainder when product $a_1 a_2 a_3.....a_{2012}a_{2013}$ is divided by 11.

I can't see remainder to be $0$ as no term will be divisible by 11 but then how to approach this problem?

Comment: All  $a_k$ are congruent to 1 modulo 11, so the remainder is 1.

Comment: hint: $12=11+1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a_k\equiv 1\pmod{11}$, so their product will also have remainder 1. Are you sure you've stated the problem correctly?